# How to force new users to post their code?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Many **new** users post questions without code examples, although the question reffers to the code 
("*I have a method that does not work... Please help me!!!*"). How to let him know that it is just necessary to put some code snippets to the question to get the answer faster and higher quality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Options are limited. You can either simply comment, or my personal approach is to do some editing myself AND leave a comment so they can see a good example of what to do when asking a question.

In the comment it can be useful to point out that questions like that risk being closed with no answers because of the difficulty involved with reading them, i.e. encourage the asker to help themselves by helping others.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is much more we can do than to specifically ask in a comment to the question.

> If you would update your question with the part of your code you are
>   having problems with we could have a better understanding .. blablabla
>   .... get your answer .. blablabla.

For a lot of new users the stackexchange format does take some adaptation, the q&a style is different from the sometimes long forum style type of things online.

Comment: I agree - best to have a conversation.  Just worth saying *the excerpt from your code where you believe the problem is happening* and making it clear than 50-line code dumps are almost as bad as no code at all